# How to pass an argument(id) from page view to page model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

let me explain a problem first.
I've got a page.
Page is basket representation with multiple records (items).

Every item has a delete button. What I want to achieve is to delete item from that basket (actually from database). But first I need to pass item id to page-model post method.

Right now that is what i got at Page view.(cshtml, dont really sure how to call it)

```
<form method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" asp-page-handler="Delete"/>
     </div>
</form>
```

And here is a page model.

```
public IActionResult OnPostDelete(int itemId)
        {
            memberData.DeleteFromBasket(itemId);
            return RedirectToPage("./Basket");
        }
```

How can i pass item id to the method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [route parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#using-a-named-route) to the button that matched the parameter name. For example:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" 
    asp-page-handler="Delete"
    asp-route-itemId="@model.ItemId" />
```

Comment: You are the best!